# Is there is any Short key to show smart guides in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: **enter image description here**]

Here is the Screen Shot mention for the smart guides

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic, GD.SE is not a tech support forum. You can setup any shortcuts you want in Photoshop if you just go to Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can add one. Click `Edit` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` > `View`, and scroll down until you find `Smart Guides`, then add a shortcut.

[image: Screenshot of Keyboard Shortcuts]